# Hive command is giving error

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-hive

I have downloaded neccessary jar files. I have also changed `.bashrc` configurations and have added CLASSPATH in `hadoop-env.sh`.
Still it is giving below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jline/ArgumentCompletor$ArgumentDelimiter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing class in the exception is part of the `jline-<version>.jar`. And this jar is included by default under the `$HIVE_HOME/lib` directory.

Check if you are missing this jar in Hive's `CLASSPATH`. If yes, you can download one from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jline/jline) and add it to the `lib/` path of Hive.